# Finding root/zeros of a function

Tags: python, function, root

I am trying to find a root of a function by using the bisection method stating that :

```
if f(a)*f(b) < 0 then a root exists, 
then you repeat with f(a)*f(c)<0 where c = (a+b)/2
```

but im not sure how to fix the code so it works properly.
This is my code but its not working properly

```
from scipy import *
from numpy import *


def rootmethod(f, a, b, tol):


    x = a
    fa = sign(eval(f))

    x = b
    fb = sign(eval(f))

    c = a + b
    iterations = 0

    if fa == 0:
        return a
    if fb == 0:
        return b

    calls = 0         
    fx = 1

    while fx != 0:
        iterations = iterations + 1
        c *= 0.5
        x = a + c
        fc = sign(eval(f))
        calls = calls + 1

        if fc*fa >= 0:
            x = a
            fx = sign(eval(f))
        if fc == 0 or abs(sign(fc)) < eps:
            fx = sign(eval(f))
            return x, iterations, calls





print rootmethod("(x-1)**3 - 1", 1, 3, 10*e-15)
```

New edit.. but still doesnt work

```
   if fa*fb < 0:

        while fx != 0:
            iterations = iterations + 1
            c = (a + b)/2.0
            x =  c
            fc = sign(eval(f))
            calls = calls + 1

            if fc*fa >= 0:
                x = c
                fx = sign(eval(f))
            if fc == 0 or abs(sign(fc)) < tol:
                fx = sign(eval(f))
                return x, iterations, calls
```

Edit: Changed c=(a+b)*2 to c=(a+b)/2 in the description of the method.

Comment: Could you specify exactly what goes wrong? i.e. interpreter error message, incorrect output (if so, example input/output)

Comment: Hi, for example .. this input ..("x**3 - 4*x**2 + 2*x -4", 2, 5, 10*e-15)  gives (2,1,1) where 2 is the root but the correct answer is 3.75.. it doesnt get there nor does it iter more than 1

Comment: abs(sign(fc)) < eps: What is this line supposed to do? where is eps defined? Doesn't sign() always return -1, 1, or 0?

Comment: my apologies eps = tol..

Comment: Okay, so as a side note that line makes no sense, since abs(sign(fc)) will always be 1 or 0, which doesn't really implement a tolerance. You should probably do abs(eval(f)) < tol or the like

Comment: I agree with @Scribble Master that `abs(sign())` is only going to give you 0 or 1, so I don't see the point in comparing that to `tol`, and `fc` is already the result of a `sign()` call, so another call doesn't seem necessary...

Comment: Stop using sign altogether - `fa*fb` will be < 0 just as well as `sign(fa)*sign(fb)`.

Comment: Also, stop using `eval` altogether. This should also be tagged "homework." If you really need to find roots, scipy has plenty of tried and true methods, and you clearly have it installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly your code was a bit of a mess. Here's some that works. Read the comments in the loop.
(BTW the solution to your given function is 2, not 3.75)

```
from scipy import *
from numpy import *


def rootmethod(f, a, b, tol):


  x = a
  fa = sign(eval(f))

  x = b
  fb = sign(eval(f))

  c = a + b
  iterations = 0

  if fa == 0:
    return a
  if fb == 0:
    return b

  calls = 0         
  fx = 1

  while 1:
    x = (a + b)/2
    fx = eval(f)

    if abs(fx) < tol:
      return x

    # Switch to new points.
    # We have to replace either a or b, whichever one will
    # provide us with a negative 
    old = b # backup variable
    b = (a + b)/2.0

    x = a
    fa = eval(f)

    x = b
    fb = eval(f)

    # If we replace a when we should have replaced b, replace a instead
    if fa*fb > 0:
      b = old
      a = (a + b)/2.0




print rootmethod("(x-1)**3 - 1", 1, 3, 0.01)
```

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant to write.

Comment: when i said the solution is 3.75 i was referring to the function i posted in the same comment.. it was different than this..

Comment: master  i have tried it but it doesnt work with other functions.. for example e^x -2 gives me 2...  x**3 - 4*x**2 + 2*x -4 gives me 2..

Answer (score 0):

I think <strike>your</strike> one problem is with:

```
    x = a + c
```

Since `c = (a + b)*.5`, you don't need to add in `a` here...

**Update**

You don't seem to check if `fa * fb < 0` to start, and I also don't see where you're narrowing your bounds: you should either reassign `a` or `b` to `c` in your loop and then recalculate `c`.

**Code** It's been a while since I played with python last, so take it with a grain of salt ^_^

```
x = a
fa = sign(eval(f))

x = b
fb = sign(eval(f))

iterations = 0

if fa == 0:
    return a
if fb == 0:
    return b

calls = 0         
fx = 1

while fa != fb:
    iterations += 1
    c = (a + b)/2.0
    x = c
    fc = eval(f)
    calls += 1

    if fc == 0 or abs(fc) < tol:
        #fx = fc not needed since we return and don't use fx
        return x, iterations, calls
    fc = sign(fc)
    if fc != fa:
        b = c
        fb = fc
    else
        a = c
        fa = fc
#error because no zero is expected to be found
```

Comment: He does have to do that operation (that's the recursiveness of the process) but it should be done at the end of the loop. Where it is now, it messes up your first calculation.

Comment: @Scribble Master, if `a` is 5 and `b` is 7, then he starts checking with `x` at 11, which makes no sense...

Comment: That's true, but he does have to average a and b AFTER the first check. Which is why I said he should move that line to the end and change it to c += a

Comment: @Scribble Master, `a` or `b` has to be assigned to `c` before that, otherwise nothing changes each iteration, and if `c` is the average of `a` and `b`, then there's no need to add `a` to `c`.

Comment: @jswolf19 Hello Please take a look at what I interpreted from what you said.. I updated the question

Comment: @Kartik, it looks better, but you still aren't reassigning `a` or `b` based on the result of `fa*fc`, so are doing the same thing in each iteration of your `while` loop.

Comment: @jswolf19  would it be possible for you to point me to the line where the fix is needed?

Comment: @Kartik, it seems you have an answer that gives you code, now, so I'll add an edit to your code that I think should work...

Comment: @jswolf19 doesnt seem to work... for different functions its just giving me the average of a and b as the root (thats the trend i found).. for example doest work for (x-1)**2 over a=0, b=3..

Comment: @Kartik, are you sure you're not hitting the threshold, then?

Comment: I edited out an excess `sign` call, but I don't think that would cause the behavior you're referring to...

Comment: @jswolf19 by threshold you mean tolerance ? i have tol=10*e-15 because if I make it 0.01.. it just takes over the RAM and goes crazy with loops

Comment: When I paste your code.. all I get is `None` for every output this is what I am executing `rootmethod("(x-2)**2", 0, 3, 0.01)`

Comment: @Kartik, yeah, I meant tolerance ^^. The only thing I can think to tell you is debugging, find out what `c` and `fc` are. You can add `print` statements in your code to make sure everything is going the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your loop should be something like this (in pseudocode, and leaving out some checking):

```
before loop:
a is lower bound
b is upper bound
Establish that f(a) * f(b) is < 0

while True:
    c = (a+b)/2
    if f(c) is close enough to 0:
        return c
    if f(a) * f(c) > 0:
        a = c
    else
        b = c
```

In other words, if the midpoint isn't the answer, then make it one of the new endpoints depending on its sign.

Comment: Since f is passed in as a string, `f(c)` wont work. Here is a tip, OP - to be able to use the inbound string as a real function, add this at the top of your method: `f = eval("lambda x : " + f)`    This will convert f from the string `"(x-1)**3-1"` to a callable function that performs that calculation - then you'll be able to call `f(a)` and `f(b)` etc. directly, instead of `x = a` followed by `fa=eval(f)`.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Nice hack using lambda that way.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the code has a simple deficiency caused by round-off errors

```
a=0.015707963267948963 
b=0.015707963267948967
c=(a+b)*.5
```

`c` is becoming `b` again (check it out!). 
You can end up in infinite loop
in case of very small tolerance like 1e-16.

```
def FindRoot( fun, a, b, tol = 1e-16 ):
  a = float(a)
  b = float(b)
  assert(sign(fun(a)) != sign(fun(b)))  
  c = (a+b)/2
  while math.fabs(fun( c )) > tol:
    if a == c or b == c: 
      break
    if sign(fun(c)) == sign(fun(b)):
      b = c
    else:
      a = c
    c = (a+b)/2
  return c
```

Now, to call the eval over and over again is not very efficient.
Here is what you can do instead

```
expr = "(x-1.0)**3.0 - 1.0"
fn = eval( "lambda x: " + expr )
print FindRoot( fn, 1, 3 )
```

Or you can put the eval and lambda definition inside the FindRoot.

Was it helpful?

```
    Reson
```